# List all sites created in network and get the language used for each site

Tags: multisite

I have multisite enabled in WordPress network to build multi language blog and using the following code to list all blogs within my network.

```
<?php $blog_list = get_blog_list(0, 'all'); foreach ($blog_list as $blog) {
  switch_to_blog( $blog['blog_id'] );
  $url = get_option( 'siteurl' );
  $name = get_option( 'blogname' );
  echo $name . ':'. $url .'<br />';
  restore_current_blog();
} ?>
```

Is there a way to get the language used on the blog from the code above?

Comment: Have you tried `get_locale()`?

Comment: `get_locale()` only get the lang attribute of the current blog we visit. What I'm trying to do is to get the language of each blog in my network site.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but I just had the same problem.

Instead of `get_locale()` (which does not return the updated value after `switch_to_blog()`), you can use `get_option( 'WPLANG' )`.

```
// ...
switch_to_blog( $otherBlogId );
$language = get_option( 'WPLANG' );

// do something with $language

restore_current_blog()
// ...
```

In my case, `get_option( 'WPLANG' )` returned an empty string when the language setting was set to "English/US". Something like the following worked:

```
$l = get_option( 'WPLANG' );
if ( empty( $l ) ) {
    $l = 'en_US';
}
```

Read more here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27346940/1107529
- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/49263